# Link when session is terminated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Hello can anyone help me solve a problem that i have.
The problem its the following every time i logout in my mvc c# web application, with multiple tabs opened, and i have a link, that opens a modal dialog window, and if the user click the link a modal dialog with login page opens, instead of what i want, that is redirect to login page.
It could possibly be done by using, in controller the following:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0){
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated){
        return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
    }
    else{
        // TODO if user is logged in
    }
}
```

but the code is never hit, it call instead the login action in account controller.

Comment: Do you have define the redirect link in the web.config  `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" .... />`?

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="3000"/>
    </authentication>

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you could conceivably make a lightweight jQuery AJAX call to your application in the onclick of your link.  If the AJAX call succeeds, you are logged in and you open the modal.  If it does not succeed, redirect to login page.

Comment: tried your solution, but it didn't work... created a method within account controller to check if it has any user loggedin and called it with $.ajax it returns true if user is loggedin and the popup still shows if no user is logged in

Comment: What authentication settings do you have enabled in IIS? What is the popup?  Is it your modal just with a login page or is ita windows auth challenge?

Comment: The popup,is a jQuery modal dialog, and would have details about a file, in the database, something like Creation Date, Type, Size and Preview... But to do that i would need to be authenticated, since the file is suposed to have legal value and is only available to the user who created it, and if not it would need to be redirected. I have enabled only Anonymous Authentication in my IIS.

Comment: So, if the AJAX call succeeds but the user is not logged in, your controller method does not have the authorize annotations setup correctly.  If it fails and the popup shows anyway, your Javascript is not correct.